# Can't add dependencies on maven pom.xml file

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.j2eeapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>j2eeapplication</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>J2EE Application Example </name>
  **<dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>**﻿﻿
  </project>
```

That part it marks an error on the opening  tag, don't know why? I need it to access httpServlet, I know to add the dependency but its giving me an error with the opening tag?THANKS

Comment: Why do you have stars in the file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the `<dependencies>` element (all `<dependency>` elements should be inside a single `<dependencies>` node):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.j2eeapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>j2eeapplication</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>J2EE Application Example </name>
  **<dependencies>**
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
     </dependency>
  **</dependencies>**
  </project>
```

Comment: it fixed it the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You're not wrapping your `<dependency>` tags inside a single `<dependencies>` node.

Comment: I didn't get the "don't seem to be defining your own groupID" part. And also the code block `<groupId> ... </version>`.